# Show object in front of the player always

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

*I have stuck in this simple problem but unable to understand that why i am unable to control it.*

I have these line of code which is displaying my canvas object in front of my player(**camRotationToWatch** object name in code) at certain rotation of the player.

```
if (camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x >= navigationCanvasXMinmumLimit && camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x <= navigationCanvasXMaximumLimit)
        {
            if (!navCanvasHasDisplay) 
            {

                navigationCanvas.SetActive(true);
                //Debug.Log(camRotationToWatch.transform.forward);
                Vector3 navCanvas = camRotationToWatch.transform.position + camRotationToWatch.transform.forward * navCanvasDisplayDistanceFromCam;
                navCanvas = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, 2f, navCanvas.z);
                navigationCanvas.transform.position = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, navCanvas.y, navCanvas.z);

                navigationCanvas.transform.rotation = camRotationToWatch.transform.rotation;

                navCanvasHasDisplay = true;

            }
        }

        else
        {
            //navigationCanvas.SetActive(false);
            if (locationPanel.activeSelf == false && infoPanel.activeSelf == false) {
                navigationCanvas.SetActive(false);
                navCanvasHasDisplay = false;
            }
        }
```

This code is actually work fine when **camRotationToWatch** object rotate from **down to up** and Canvas show at correct position but as I try to to rotate **camRotationToWatch** from **up to down** it display(active) Canvas at very top position. How can I restrict canvas to show at same position (*No matter player rotate from up to down or down to up*) but display on front of the player object?

Comment: Could you just parent the canvas to the player and forget the script?

Comment: i can but it will also rotate up and down, left and right which is not correct

Comment: @Absinthe i will rotate according to camera which i seriously not want to do

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you're looking to do. Do you want the canvas always in front of the player at a set height?

Comment: yes, i am looking for this

Comment: So again, just parent it to the root transform of your player, not his head

Comment: Try edit canvas render mode to World Space.

Comment: @Absinthe there is no root trasform of the player

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Yes there is, everything has a root transform! https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Is it possible that you make a video of the problem please?

Comment: Add the hirerchy tree to your question please.

Comment: which object you are willing to look

Answer (score 2):

Kinda hard trying to figure out what exactly you want to do. But this did what I think you where trying to do

```cs
public GameObject follow; // The object you want to rotate around
public float distance = 2; // Distance to keep from object

private void Update() {
    Vector3 forward = follow.transform.forward;
    forward.y = 0; // This will result in Vector3.Zero if looking straight up or down. Carefull

    transform.position = follow.transform.position + forward * distance;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, Vector3.up);
}
```

I believe your "unexpected behavior" is due to the use of euler angles since they are not always entirely predictable. Try using Quaternions or Vector3.Angle() when possible.

If you want to limit the angle (say... if looking down or up more than 45° disable the object) you could do the following:

```cs
if (Vector3.Angle(forward, follow.transform.forward) > maxAngle) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't a complete answer but something that might help.  This line:

```
Vector3 navCanvas = camRotationToWatch.transform.position + camRotationToWatch.transform.forward * navCanvasDisplayDistanceFromCam;
```

You are creating a position at a fixed distance from `camRotationToWatch`.  But if that object is looking up or down, that position is not **horizontally** at `navCanvasDisplayDistanceFromCam`.  If it's looking straight up, then this position is in fact directly above.

So when you do this to set a fixed vertical height:

```
navCanvas = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, 2f, navCanvas.z);
```

you aren't getting the distance from `camRotationToWatch` that you think you are.
Instead of using `camRotationToWatch.transform.forward`, create a vector from it and zero out the Y component, and normalize before using it to offset the position. (You will need to watch out for zero length vectors with that though).
Whether that fixes your problem or not, it's too hard to guess but it should help improve your results some.

EDIT: Here is an example of how you can avoid the issue with the canvas being too close:

```
Vector3 camForward = camRotationToWatch.transform.forward;
camForward.y = 0;
if (camForward.magnitude == 0)
{
    //TODO: you'll need to decide how to deal with a straight up or straight down vector
}
camForward.Normalize();
//Note: now you have a vector lying on the horizontal plane, pointing in
//the direction of camRotationToWatch
Vector3 navCanvas = camRotationToWatch.transform.position + camForward * 
    navCanvasDisplayDistanceFromCam;
//Note: if you want the canvas to be at the player's height (or some offset from), 
//use the player's y
navCanvas = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, Player.transform.y, navCanvas.z);
navigationCanvas.transform.position = navCanvas;
```

Again, this might not fix all your issues but will help to ensure your canvas lies at a set distance **horizontally** from the Player and will also compensate for the player's up and down motion.

Comment: How can i get forward of the player ? this is only the way to do this job

Comment: Actually i cant fixed the height as my player my player position is changing up and down also

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an example with some comments of how it works.  Hopefully this helps to understand better.