# Determine the player facing/front position at fixed height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The **ways I know that** to get **player front position**

1. Player position & Player forward

   frontPosition= player.transform.position + player.transform.forward * distance;
2. The seconds way (possibly)

> Make a gameobject child to my player and place it on front and use its
>   position

is there any any alternative avaiable to determine player front position?

*Note: Dear readers, can you skip this question that why I don't want to use above techniques it?*

Comment: What is wrong with number 1? Why do you want an alternative?

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked on [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There really must be a good reason why you cannot use the built-in functionality available to you for this purpose. If so, please explain the constraints on the question - otherwise solutions we propose may not meet your requirements because of conditions we're not aware of.

Comment: Hope you will find the details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321850/show-canvas-in-front-of-the-player-but-at-same-position-always